# Problema al devolver una lista de objetos JSON con AJAX, no consigo acceder a las propiedades del objeto

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net, ajax

Buenas,
Tengo este servicio web:

```
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string ObtenirProvinciaByPoblacio(int CodiProvincia)
    {
        clsCRUD _ou2 = new clsCRUD();
        try
        {
            _ou2.Connectar();
            List<clsProvincies> LlistaProvincies = clsDALProvincies.getList(_ou2, CodiProvincia);
            _ou2.Desconnectar();
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string resultat_Json = jss.Serialize(LlistaProvincies);
            return resultat_Json;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

El cual me devuelve una lista de objetos (En este caso solo hay un objecto en la lista, pero no viene al caso). Y en la función de ajax tengo esto:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "/WebServiceCV.asmx/ObtenirProvinciaByPoblacio",
                data: "{'CodiProvincia': '" + Codiprovincia + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {                                          

                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        alert(item);
                    });                  
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("arriva al failure");
                }
            });
```

En el alert me muestra bien el objeto: `[{"Codi":25,"Nom":"LLEIDA"}]`
Pero no consigo de ninguna forma coger los valores `Codi` y `Nom` para trabajar con ellos. En teoria sería `item.Codi` o `item.Nom` ¿verdad?
He intentado varias opciones pero no consigo nada.

Comment: Revertí la última actualización porque mostraba la respuesta en la pregunta. Xavier, debes marcar una respuesta como aceptada o de lo contrario aceptar tu propia respuesta

Comment: Recuerda que el valor devuelto es un string. Por lo tanto tiene que parsearlo a json. JSON.parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya me funciona, gracias.
El código queda así:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/WebServiceCV.asmx/ObtenirProvinciaByPoblacio",
                data: "{'CodiProvincia': '" + Codiprovincia + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {                                          
                    var valors = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    $.each(valors, function (index, item) {
                        console.log(item.Codi);
                        console.log(item.Nom);
                    });
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("arriva al failure");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hola javier, lo mejor seria que marques una respuesta como correcta, en lugar de comentarlo.

Comment: bien aplicaste el `var valors = JSON.parse(data.d);` esa linea es la clave ya que estabas enviando el json como string

Comment: Está bien que publiques cómo quedó el código al final para futura referencia para otros usuarios. Pero por favor, marca la respuesta que te fue útil como aceptada.

Answer (score 3):

Con tan solo hacer `item.Codi` deberia devolver el 25 y con `item.Nom` el nombre.

Quedaría así tu código:

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        console.log(item.Codi);
                        console.log(item.Nom);
});
```

DEMO

```js
var data = [{"Codi":25,"Nom":"LLEIDA"}];

$.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        console.log(item.Codi);
                        console.log(item.Nom);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si solo te interesa un unico item de la lista porque no usas:

```
List<clsProvincies> LlistaProvincies = clsDALProvincies.getList(_ou2, CodiProvincia);
clsProvincies provincia = LlistaProvincies.First();
_ou2.Desconnectar();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string resultat_Json = jss.Serialize(provincia);
return resultat_Json;
```

Como veras al usar el First() solo tomas un unico item que se enviara como `json` al cliente.

---

Por otro lado veo que usas `$.each` en donde estas recorriendo cada item del array que devuelve el json, lo que no entiendo es como puede ser que `data` genera en cada item un array en lugar en lugar de ser un item simple.

No evaluaste poner un breakpoint en el javascript para poder inspeccionar el contenido de `data` ? puede usar las tools del browser para realizar esto

Comment: Gracias por la aportación, me lo apunto ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Comentas que "En el alert me muestra bien el objeto: `[{"Codi":25,"Nom":"LLEIDA"}]"`

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    alert(item);
});
```

Revisa la variable data, es posible que se te haya devuelto `[[{"Codi":25,"Nom":"LLEIDA"}]]`.

Si es así, tendrías que poner `item[0].Codi`.

Answer (score 1):

Que pasa si en lugar de usar

```
var valors = JSON.parse(data.d);
```

Devuelves uan clase como json sin serializarla

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<clsProvincies> ObtenirProvinciaByPoblacio(int CodiProvincia)
{

    clsCRUD _ou2 = new clsCRUD();

    _ou2.Connectar();
    List<clsProvincies> LlistaProvincies = clsDALProvincies.getList(_ou2, CodiProvincia);
    _ou2.Desconnectar();

    return LlistaProvincies;
}
```

Como veras devuelves directo la lista sin serializar a json, veras que se devuelve directo la lista de provincias y no un string

Answer (score 0):

Por el alert que muestras (`[{"Codi":25,"Nom":"LLEIDA"}]`), el resultado devuelto es un array de objetos y no un objeto en sí. Así que no lo accederías con `item.Codi` e `item.Nom` sino con `item[0].Codi` e `item[0].Nom` (sólo hay un objeto así que el índice sería 0)

Comment: $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                            alert(item[0].Codi);
                        });  --> el alert me muestra "undefinied"

Comment: @Xavier debes hacer debug con console, porque usas Ajax, es mas alert no es un medio de debug de javascript/

Comment: @Xavier: ¿Parseas `data` primero? Haz `data = JSON.parse(data);` al principio del success.